# Integrating react locomotive scroll while using framer-motion's scroll trigger animations is buggy

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, react-animations, locomotive-scroll

I have a few framer-motion scroll trigger animations, nothing too complicated, in my current application and I wanted to integrate locomotive scroll using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-locomotive-scroll.

However, when I add it and start scrolling, the app flickers like crazy when scrolling to bottom and I noticed 2 scrollbars.

Anyone dealt with this and found a solution? Maybe I don't use this library but I couldn't find an alternative.